# build and run Espresso tests having only application apk

Tags: instrumentation, android-espresso

Is it possible to build espresso tests having only application apk, witout sources? 
`connectedAndroidTestMinSdkVersion_14_Debug`  gradle task is willing to rebuild application. I have seen earlier a guide how to setup test build environment seperated from application build, using gradle, but unfortunately cant find it again.

By the way, wat is the base solution to run espresso tests in continious integeration if application under test is built by Ant scripts?